# An approach for this question accompanied by a solution

Tags: trigonometry, summation, fractions

This question is very elementary when compared to the level of problems asked on this site. However, I am preparing for the Joint Entrance Examination in India and I needed some help in finding an approach and I would like to solicit the answer as well.

The value of 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{13} \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{(k-1)\pi}{6}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{6}\right)}=?$$

Also, I would greatly appreciate it if your answer includes mathematics used in junior high.

Comment: Junior high math? Unlikely with that kind of trigonmetric sum.

Comment: "13" terms is not trivial but neither is it an unreasonably large number- if nothing else, evaluate each term:

Comment: The Joint Entrance Examination is given by students in senior high, given that the mathematics, physics and chemistry is on another level.